# Namespaces for .NET JWT token validation: System vs. Microsoft

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt

I am trying to use JWT to authenticate a Node application to an ASP.NET Web API.

In ASP.NET, I am using .NET 4.5.1 and nuget package `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` 5.0.0

What I don't understand is, why the namespaces are mixed between `Microsoft` and `System`.

For example:

```
var tokenReader = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

tokenReader.ValidateToken(token, 
                new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateAudience = false
            },
                out validatedToken);
```

The main `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` is in the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` namespace, but the `TokenValidationParameters` class and its dependencies are in the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` namespace, and possibly collide with similar classes in the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens` namespace.

Is this by design or is this a possible sign of a version mismatch somewhere else?

Comment: Have you learned anything about this? I'm facing the same thing right now.

Comment: Can you build an [mcve]?

Comment: Are you using WIF 3.5?  If so, are you able to migrate from WIF 3.5 to 4.5?  That should clear out the (deprecated) `Microsoft` namespaces.

Comment: did you start with System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 5.0.0 or with lower version and upgrade?

Comment: @DaveAlperovich I think I started with one of the RC versions. I'm using 5.0.0 now, but it still needs both System.IdentityModel and Microsoft.IdentityModel classes to work.

Comment: @TarkaDaal, Yes, 5.0 depends on Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens. 4.0 did not. But the earliest version of 5RC had this dependency.  are you having build issues?

Comment: @DaveAlperovich No, I'm not having build issues. I'm having problems understanding why it's like this. Why the mix of namespaces, why does one require classes from the other, which is newest, which one should I be using (for ASP.NET Core), that sort of thing.

Comment: @TarkaDaal I see. Moving around namespaces is very common. I agree this was a bad architecture decision. WIF was first made independent, then refactored to be lighter (as all assemblies are, which meant re-posing dependencies. So, to summarize, `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` was first deprecated, then brought back as a dependency in 5.0. Does that explain the overlap?

Comment: @DaveAlperovich That helps explain some of the history, although I'd like more detail. And also I want to know which ones I should be using, and for which purposes.

Comment: @TarkaDaal, I will add a more detailed answer, but for now understand that `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` is a dependency. You should always use the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` methods and classes when available.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you take a look at the dependency for

[nuget System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 4.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/4.0.2.206221351)

vs

[nuget System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 5.0](http://System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt%205.0.0)

you'll see that 5.0 has a dependency on

> Dependencies
>
> .NETFramework 4.5.1
>
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens (>=5.0.0)

that 4.0 didn't have. In fact, no previous version did.

Microsoft is re-architect-ing their frameworks to be more light weight. In a framework the size of ASP.NET, you will have many functional redundancies.

To make WIF lighter, while remaining backwards compatible, the decision was made to remove the redundant functionality from libraries like `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` no longer depend on `System.IdentityModel.Tokens`, but instead on `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens`. One of the unfortunate results is that both layers expose the same methods.

Comment: I see that dependency as well - so it's likely that this is intentional, possibly by design, even if it creates confusion.  Any idea if this will last forever or if one of these two namespaces will eventually win?

Comment: @wrschneider, that is still being decided between teams. they're aware of the conflict, but this way is still backwards compatible

Comment: @DaveAlperovich This is a good answer, but can you clear up which version we should be using? Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens is the old version of the library? Or the new one?

Comment: @TarkaDaal, isee the confusion.  `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` is the **OLDER** Library. It has been re-introduced as a dependency. `System.IdentityModel` has been removed as a dependency. You should always use the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` methods and classes when available The unfortunate part of this backward compatible, light weight architecture, is that the dependency library exposes the same methods. Ideally,  `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` would be private methods or differently named. I hope I'm clarifying rather than further confusing...

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, when you instance you must provide the entire namespace to inform the compiler which Class and namespace you're referencing. So, you will avoid conflicts.

Microsoft.Identity is deprecated in NET 4.5. And you can see more here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/256c6bcd-6752-4487-b2e8-6c63f4efb9e9/difference-between-microsoftidentitymodel-and-systemidentitymodel?forum=Geneva

Comment: You could also define an alias in the using statement, but I guess that's not the point here: the issue is that you can't pass an object of the wrong class as a parameter when it's in the wrong namespace. That means you need to write converter or adapter classes for each of them. This answer does not consider this aspect.

Comment: That's right Thomas (alias) but you can utilize the parameter in your complete format (referencing the namespace/class). Anyway, the answer of WHY the conflict exists (the user's final question) is here above.

Comment: If Microsoft.Identity* is deprecated in .NET 4.5, why is ASP.NET Core's `JwtBearerOptions`class configured using types from it?

Comment: in 5.0 this is no longer the case. For the sake of making System.IdentityModel.TokensJwt lighter, the library is again dependent on Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens

Comment: The problem is focused in two subjects: 1) library makers are referencing the lighter/faster code (namespace) of the NET framework;  2) but MS warns about these functions are deprecated in NET 4.5. Why? Only the lib makers can provide the answer.