# Benefit to full reference paths for object declarations?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is this probably a stupid question? Sure, but i'm more or less just curious to hear other peoples opinions. So Is there a benefit to using the full reference path for an object declaration? MSDN only seemed to mention that it might help when overloading controls or declaring your own class that is already included in the visual basic language.

What i'm referring to is a declaration like so

```
Dim MyFile As New System.IO.File
```

In visual studio if you `Import System.IO` then it will tell you that the name can be simplified to just

```
Dim MyFile As New File
```

But is there any other benefit or does it really matter whether you just use `File` or the full reference to `System.IO.File`. Is this simply so that if you did not want to `Import System.IO` you could still use the `File` Class? I'm sure that it's the latter of the two, and its simply just if you do not want to import, but is it better practice to use `System.IO.File` instead of just `File`? And honestly I'm more or less just curious, because i know either way it'll compile and run.

Comment: You can do it MAINLY when you have conflicts betweens classes/methods  with same name but by different libraries. See an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526950/namespaces-for-net-jwt-token-validation-system-vs-microsoft/38897518?noredirect=1#comment65161072_38897518

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons this exists is to solve name conflicts.

For example:
Lets say you have a class:

```
CompanyOne.ProductX.Customer
```

and another class:

```
CompanyTwo.ProductY.Customer
```

If you import both namespaces (`CompanyOne.ProductX`, and `CompanyTwo.ProductY`), and then declare a `Customer` object, you'll get a compile-time error.  It won't know which `Customer` object you were trying to instantiate.

So to resolve this you would use the fully-qualified name of the class to declare your variable.

Comment: That's a fair point, I'm just for whatever realizing now that I really don't need any of this system garbage, I guess that's just how i learned and have been doing it ever since.

Comment: Long "path" gen be made shorter by using aliases `Imports comp1 = CompanyOne.ProductX`. Use then as `comp1.Customer`. But on my point of view in most cases it makes hard to read/understand code