# What is the different between System.IdentityModel.Tokens & Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens? Which one should I use in an ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-identity-3

We can find two separate packages in the NuGet gallery:

- [System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/)
- [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens/)

Both seem to receive regularly updated and have millions of downloads.

I know that `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` has a dependency on `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens`, but I don't know which one should I use in my ASP.NET Core 2.0 application.

I'm using `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` now and it is good enough to create JWT tokens and validate them.

Do I need to add `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` to my project and change any code?

PS: I am not using Azure services in this project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you pointed out System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt has a dependency on Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens

[image: Dependency]

As suggested in [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526950/namespaces-for-net-jwt-token-validation-system-vs-microsoft) you should use the **System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt** nuget as Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens is the older library.

Comment: It's the opposite of what you said.

System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt (starts 2013) is much older than Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens (starts 2018)
See: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki 

Regarding Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens - "This is a newer, faster version of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt that has additional functionality."

Comment: PhilB is right. System.IdentityModel.Token.Jwt is a legacy tool that should be replaced with Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.